# Confirmation dialog on Remove vertex and link in JointJS library

Tags: javascript, angular, backbone.js, jointjs

I'm trying to add confirmation dialog before deleting `vertex` and `link` for `Finite State Machine demo` of `Joint Js lib v-2.2`.

Source code ref:

https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/fsa

https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/joint/demo/fsa/src/fsa.js

I want to trigger `built in remove event` only after users make confirmation on dialog.

I'm trying like

```
graph: any;
paper: any;

this.graph = new joint.dia.Graph; 

this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: $('#paper'),
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  gridSize: 1,
  model: this.graph,
  background: {
    color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)'
  }
});

 /* not working */
 this.paper.on('tool:remove', function(linkView, evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
    linkView.remove();
  }
});


/* not working */
this.paper.on('element:delete', function(elementView, evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
    elementView.model.remove();
  }
});
```

I also tried it from here but not working.
[JointJS - handling a Link Delete click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108783/jointjs-handling-a-link-delete-click)

Comment: Are you doing it using both angular and backbone?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use the ToolsView's "Remove" button to delete the element on your graph.
If so, add the "action" option to your "Remove" button constructor, like so:

```
const elToolsView = new dia.ToolsView({
    tools: [
        new elementTools.Remove({
            x: "100%",
            y: 0,
            offset: { x: 10, y: -10 },
            action: () => confirmRemoval(el2) //--- ADD THIS
        })
    ]
});

function confirmRemoval(cell) {
    showDialog({
        text: "Are you sure you want to remove this element?",
        yesText: "Remove",
        yes: () => cell.remove(), //only when the user confirms, delete
        noText: "Cancel"
    });
}
```

A fully working example can be found here: https://www.jointjs.com/blog/demo-friday-confirmation-dialogs